# Invalid Write Size using C++ Vectors at Address 0x0

Tags: c++, vector, valgrind

I am working on bettering my knowledge in C++ and I wrote this program to try to work on vectors. The program itself is syntactically correct, but when I compile I get a SEG FAULT 11. So then I ran Valgrind on the code and I'm getting an `invalid write size 4` error and also `Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`. Here is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int TTO = 2147483648;
int main()
{
    int n, s, p, q, i;
    cin >> n >> s >> p >> q;
    vector<int> a;
    a[0] = s % TTO;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = (a[i-1]*p+q) % TTO;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    a.erase(unique(a.begin(), a.end()), a.end());
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What can I do to have this not `SEG FAULT`?

**Edit**: The input I used was `3 1 1 1`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the case, but when *undefined behavior* is invoked, anything can happen.

Comment: `resize()` your vector before using it here: `a[0]`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Like this `a.resize()`?

Comment: @MikeCAT There's definitely UB invoked.

Comment: @EliSadoff Like `a.resize(n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector has no elements, so accessing even `a[0]` is illegal (more precisely, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Give your vector an initial size:

```
vector<int> a(n);
             ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that vectors needed an initial size. I'm trying to get better at debugging my C++ code and recognizing UB.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
vector<int> a;
```

creates an empty vector, so accessing any element (including 0) by operator [] is UB. Either call `std::vector::resize()` or add new elements by `std::vector::push_back()` or `std::vector::emplace_back()`